# jQuery Flot: Switch between day, week, and month dates

Tags: jquery, flot

I have data points for every day between January 1 to December 31.

What I'd like to do is let users switch been Day, Week, and Month views of that data.

Is there a way to do this with jQuery Flot?

Comment: You could simply modify the dataset yourself and re-plot it. I do not think flot will do this for you - but I am not certain. FWIW - in my charts I just re-call my JSON web services with the desired x-axis data interval specified and re-plot that when users change the scale.

Answer (score 0):

Flot can't automatically re-sample your data; you'll need to do that either in JS using your original input, or server-side.